# Cucumber/Selenium newbie trying to use RoR session-data in step-definitions ... and failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, selenium, cucumber

I'm spending my first few days with cucumber/selenium trying to figure out whether RBB is the thing I want to use in my latest RoR project.

My setting: Rails 2.3.5, selenium-client 1.2.17, cucumber 0.4.4 etc, quite current in my view.

Following the instructions on https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Setting-up-Selenium I got cucumber/selenium sorts of up and running. Simple step-definitions do work and do produce outpout that makes sense (I dont usually expect more on my first few days with anything :-) ).

My problem: I am trying to access the rails session-hash in my step-definition...and failing miserably. Refering to "session" in any "given"-clause just presents me with "undefined method `session' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)"

Is there any secret handshake I am missing in the docs???? Anything that has to be configured my my environment so using the session-hash is possible?

Regards
Michael

Comment: What is it you are trying to do with the session information? Generally accessing implementation details like sessions from your cucumber step definitions is to be avoided. Cucumber steps are acceptance tests and should be implementation independent. Cucumber is accessing your site as a user would. It is better to look at  what your application is doing i.e. which page you are on and what you can see on the screen.

Comment: Thanks for your comment!

Yepp, I already saw recommendations like yours. Perhaps when I am on firmer ground concerning BDD I will follow it. Its just that I prefer doing things because I understand it, not because I fail doing otherwise (esp. in such an early stage) :-)

Answer (score 0):

This should happen right out of the box. If you add a debugger line right to a step definition you should be able to type "session" and see something like:

{:session_id=>"f978d4220252b7e1ca51fb7319d5a365", "flash"=>{}}

Comment: Thanks, that sounds promising, esp. the bit about the debugger!!

Comment: Funny thing is: As long as I use

Webrat.configure do |config|
  config.mode = :rails
  [...]

I can access session information in the debugger. As soon as I switch to :selenium I cant anymore...*THINK*